# Synaptic does not work

Tags: synaptic

since I don't know when Synaptic does not work.
When I launch Synaptic from the dash, the icon appears for some seconds, that's all. On the other hand, Synaptic works, when I launch it from the terminal.
How can I fix this?

```
$ synaptic-pkexec 
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic ===
Authentication is required to run the Synaptic Package Manager
Authenticating as: Christian Hartmann,,, (christian) Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie 
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED === 
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized 
This incident has been reported.
```

Comment: Are you trying to run from a terminal window or from the Unity dash?  Try from the terminal using "sudo synaptic".  If this does not work, post the error you get.

Comment: as I said: it does not work when I launch it from the Unity dash. From the terminal it works fine. Only that I find the dash more comfortable and that I hate it, if something does not work as it should

Comment: Try reinstalling it.

Comment: tried to reinstall it several times. Nothing changes!

Comment: I tried synaptic-pkexec:
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic ===
Authentication is required to run the Synaptic Package Manager
Authenticating as: Christian Hartmann,,, (christian)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the output on your last comment.

Comment: $ synaptic-pkexec
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic ===
Authentication is required to run the Synaptic Package Manager
Authenticating as: Christian Hartmann,,, (christian)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.

Comment: Please try `groups christian` and give us the output.  I just want to check whether user `christian` has the correct permissions.  [I am assuming from the output above, that `christian` is your username.]

Comment: This started happening to me on a Ubuntu 14.04 system after a kernel (?) update quite a while ago.  The synaptic-pkexec that was in the .desktop did not work, just as you described. I made a new .desktop file with the command `gksudo synaptic` and it works fine.  Note: I use LXDE desktop so I can't help with how to get this to work in Unity, hence posting as a comment.

Comment: to Juan: actually I do not know what it means to try "groups christian"

Comment: to organic marble: in unity it works the same. But I don't like the idea that there is something different from what it should be.

Answer (score 2):

This happened for me just now on Ubuntu Mate, and after a bit of searching I found a solution for another distro but which I could adapt to my distro as well.

The "synaptic-pkexec" program is just a script that starts synaptic using "pkexec". "pkexec" launches a dialog to ask for your password, but instead of just reading /etc/sudoers (like sudo) it uses PolicyKit which uses an "authentication agent" that needs to be running in the background.

Apparently, the authentication agent was not running because I had somehow managed to uncheck the **PolicyKit Authentication Agent** from my list of **Startup Applications**. (not that a agent/daemon belongs among applications ...)
I checked it in the **Startup Applications** Preferences, logged out and back in again and now "synaptic-pkexec" and other admin programs work.