# After upgrading Lubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10, "Software & Updates" does not work properly

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, update-manager

After upgrading, I am unable to change any setting in "Software & Updates" (e.g. remove sources), but if I run in the terminal "sudo software-propertis-gtk" I am able to change settings as usual. It seems to me that the dialog that asks for my admin password is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this problem. For some reason, after the upgrade, the PolicyKit Authentication Agent was removed from my list of Startup Applications. I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/931961/614845).